# Combining two geodesic curves into one geodesic curve

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

On a complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with positive injectivity radius $R$, a geodesic curve $g_1:[a,b]\rightarrow M$ enters a point, $g_1(b_1)=p$ with tangent
$v$ and another geodesic curve $g_2:[b,c]\rightarrow M$ exists the point, $g_2(b)=p$ with the same tangent $v$.

Is the following true? There is a parametrisation and
some nontrivial interval $[d,e]\subset[a,c]$ and a geodesic curve $g$ such that for some $f\in(d,e)$, $g{[d,f]}\subset g_1[a,b]$ and $g[f,e]\subset g_2[b,c]$.

Essentially, if a geodesic curve $g_1$ interpolates a point $p$ at its endpoint and another $g_2$ interpolates 
$p$ at its start point, and they both have the tangent $v$ at $p$, then (some nontrivial subset of them) can be combined into a single geodesic
curve.

Attempt: I think this follows from local uniqueness of the exponential map at $p$ due to $R>0$.

Comment: Hint: (1) Besides the uniqueness, you should also use the short-term existence of geodesics near $b$. (2) Eventually, you can even take $[d,e]=[a,c]$ and the injectivity radius is irrelevant.